# How to change google chrome home page/startup page from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new in chrome extension development and just trying from 3 days to change the homePage, Startup Page from background js.

I have found one solution that redirects a new tab to the URL of our choice but It is so irritating as on every new tab it is redirecting.

I have found this link in chrome extension development docs but could not found any way to do it.

[overriding extension settings](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/settings_override/)

Can anybody help?

Comment: Extensions can change the home page via [settings_override](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override). Extensions can change the newtab page that's displayed on creating a new empty tab the link you found is correct. Here's the official demo extension: [link](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/mv2-archive/api/override/override_igoogle).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for replying but as I mentioned above that I want to change it using background js(using javascript) not by html file.

Comment: Extensions can't do that. The only thing they can do in the background script is to listen for chrome.tabs.onCreated and then redirect it, but you will probably see flicker of the old contents.

Comment: @wOxxOm then how i do it using html file? i can simply write inside menifest. What you told me? i did not understand

Comment: @wOxxOm can we dynamically change url in html page? i mean using ajax i get a new url and then pass it in the meta tag inside html page ?

Comment: The js script of the page can use chrome.tabs.update or location.assign to redirect to a new URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm i have write an alert in js script inside the html file that I have included in url override but it is not working. any idea?